# How to delete column in html from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, delete-row

[image][image]

I have a table and I want to delete a column when `Variables.Product.URUN_KOD == '310'` I can delete this row first get to `310` but get the second time it deletes automatically first column's last element you can see in the picture. Thanks

```js
$("#SigortaliCustomerDataTable tr").find('td:eq(5),th:eq(5)').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <hr />
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="SigortaliCustomerDataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Müşteri No</th>
                    <th>Ad Soyad</th>
                    <th>TCKN/VKN</th>
                    <th>Yazışma Adresi</th>
                    <th>İletişim</th>
                    <th style='width:50px'>Pay</th>
                    <th style='width:50px'></th>
                    <th style='width:50px'></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better? Do you want to remove all 5th column for each row? And your code is doing that for only first row? Is it true?

Comment: yeap you are right

Comment: But your code is doing it for all the rows? There is no problem?

Comment: no you see just one row in run code snippet my problem is starting  when i add others rows you can see in the pictures

Comment: @Mustafa :  can u share your complete code

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the remove by using this code. No need of any iteration:

```
 $("#SigortaliCustomerDataTable tr").find("th:eq(5), td:eq(5)").remove();
```

Please check this fiddle I created for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2cqow1y5/

Comment: please look at my other pictures result is same just last added data is looks like right on the table

Comment: run this code after all the rows are added into the table. You create a variable with a boolean value to false and if your condition `Variables.Product.URUN_KOD == '310'` is true then you can change the variable to true. And at the end just check if the result of that variable is true then run that script.

Comment: Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cqow1y5/. And dont forget to upvote if this works for you.